# Ubuntu - trouble securing *.mydomain.com and *.sub.mydomain.com using different certs

Tags: apache, ssl, subdomain, lets-encrypt

I just added a subdomain to my site and am trying to get SSL working. Previously I had SSL working on example.net and www.example.net using a cert from namespace.com.

With the subdomain, things are not quite working.

Here is what I have in DNS entries:

```
CNAME: www.sub.example.net is an alias of example.net

A:     sub.example.net  directs to IP

CNAME: www.example.net is an alias of example.net   

A:     example.net directs to IP
```

Here is my example.net conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.net
   Redirect permanent / https://example.net/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.net
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/example/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/example/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/example.net.key
SSLCertificateFile /root/example.net.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/example.net.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

And my sub.example conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.example.net
        ServerAlias www.sub.example.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sub.example
        Redirect permanent / https://sub.example.net/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName sub.example.net
ServerAlias www.sub.example.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/sub.example
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.net/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.net/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to `sub.example.net` and `www.sub.example.net` then all is well.

If I go to `example.net` all is well.

However, when I go to `www.example.net` I get error about the cert only being valid for `sub.example.net` and `*.sub.example.net`.

So for some reason the `www` in front of `example.net` is having apache not look at the namespace.com wildcard cert that I have for `example.net`.

Now, I created the subdoamin certs via

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual -d *.sub.example.net -d sub.example.net --agree-tos --no-bootstrap --manual-public-ip-logging-ok --preferred-challenges dns-01 --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

I have a feeling I have some weird combo of apache conf settings and DNS entries that are causing this behavior. Any idea what I did wrong?

thanks,
Brian

Comment: Just add `ServerAlias www.example.net` to the first vhost. I don’t see this domain inside any vhost. Thus the default vhost is served.

Comment: The CNAME DNS entry doesn't handle that?

Comment: @Brian: DNS CNAME will not handle this. It applies only to DNS, not to HTTP(S) server configuration.

Comment: No. Apache operates using its configuration, it doesn’t care about any dns.

Comment: Ok, I guess I thought when someone types in a url that they couldn't possibly arrive at an apache server without DNS first resolving the address.

Comment: @Brian: it is true that the cannot arrive at the server without getting the IP address for the name via DNS. But, CNAME is no HTTP level redirect but just a DNS level alias: if you have a CNAME for www.example.com pointing to example.com it will use this to get the IP address from DNS but it will still use the original name inside the HTTP requests and the TLS handshake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So for some reason the www in front of example.net is having apache not look at the namespace.com wildcard cert that I have for example.net.

You don't have a ServerAlias defined for `www.example.net` which means it will not be able to find an exact match for the domain name. In this case it uses the first of your virtual hosts in the configuration, whichever this is in your case.

Comment: Not "any", the very first defined in the order.

Comment: @emix: correct, but the order is unknown in this case - that's why any.

Comment: Your answer suggests this behaves randomly.

Comment: @emix: I've edited the answer to make this more clear now.